# grep - regular expression - match till a specific word

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Lets say I have a file with lines like this

```
abcefghijklxyz
abcefghijkl
```

I want to get only the string between `abc` and the end of the line. End of the line can be defined as the normal end of line or the string `xyz`.

My question is

How can I get only the matched string using `grep` and regular expressions? For example, the expected output for the two lines shown above would be

```
efghijkl
efghijkl
```

I don't want the starting and ending markers.

**What I have tried till now**

```
grep -oh "abc.*xyz"
```

I use Ubuntu 13.04 and Bash shell.

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know what is wrong with this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this line chops leading `abc` and **ending** `xyz` (if there was) away, and gives you the part you need:

```
grep -oP '^abc\K.*?(?=xyz$|$)'
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo "abcefghijklxyz
abcefghijkl"|grep -oP '^abc\K.*?(?=xyz$|$)'
efghijkl
efghijkl
```

another example with `xyz` in the middle of the text:

```
kent$  echo "abcefghijklxyz
abcefghijkl
abcfffffxyzbbbxyz
abcffffxyzbbb"|grep -oP '^abc\K.*?(?=xyz$|$)'
efghijkl
efghijkl
fffffxyzbbb
ffffxyzbbb
```

Comment: +1 I dont know who downvoted this. I am checking if this is working for my actual data.

Comment: downvote is welcomed, only if with explanation, so that people can learn why the solution is not good enough(or bad). the Downvoter, would you pls post a short comment?

Comment: @Alfe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions then search `\K` typing it is easier than `(?<=..)` ;)

Comment: @thefourtheye you could use `.*?abc\K.*?(?=xyz|$)` to extract the text between **the first abc** and **the first xyz or EOL**, if this is required.

Comment: +1. Could you explain what that funky regex is doing. OR link to some documentation which would. Thanks.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer which part do you have problem? `.*?` means non-greedy, `(?=...)` is positive look ahead. `\K` you can find in previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Using sed:

```
sed -n '/abc/{s/.*abc\(.*\)/\1/;s/xyz.*//;p}' input
```

*Produces:*

```
efghijkl
efghijkl
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like this:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=abc)[^x]*' file
efghijkl
efghijkl
```

It fetches everything after `abc` and until it finds a `x`.

---

Based on [Kent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20373402/1983854) (not to copy, but for completeness) you can `grep` all within `abc` and `xyz` (or end of line):

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=abc).*(?=xyz|$)' file
efghijklxyz
efghijkl
```

Comment: I don't want the `xyz` as well. Can that also be stripped with regex?

Comment: Yes, @Alfe, as I say in my answer.

Comment: @fedorqui Alfe is correct. Instead of `x`, how can I use a word?

Comment: Well, @thefourtheye for this you may check Kent's answer.

Comment: I'd propose `echo abcefghxijklxyz | grep -Po '(?<=abc).*?(?=xyz)'`, no?

Comment: @thefourtheye I just updated my answer with a look-behing and look-forward.

Comment: Consider input like `abcefghxijklxyzhxijklxyz`.  Depending on the requirements the `.*` or the `.*?` fits.

Comment: @Alfe I updated the answer using part of Kent's approach, note you also need to indicate `$` for the cases when `xyz` is not found. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Alfe The solution you suggested in the comment also works fine :) I would upvote it, if you put that as an answer.

Comment: Thnks but let the faster ones get the merits :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just remove what you do not like:

```
awk '/^abc/{sub(/^abc/,x);sub(/xyz.*$/,x)}1' file
efghijkl
efghijkl
```

`xyz.*$` represent everything from `xyz` to end of line.